# OpenJS-Grid-master v2 and mysql

Tags: php

I get the error `Unknown column 'first.' in 'field list'`. I have database named "try", a table named "first", with fields "id(int)" and "name(char)". Its just a sample table I am using to show its data in a grid, but am getting this Error. I have edited those default html and ajax files as follows:

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css" title="openJsGrid"/>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-                          1.8.22.custom.css"/>-->
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>-->
<script src="root.js"></script>
<script src="grid.js"></script>

<script >
$(function() {
$(".users").grid();
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Users</h2>
<table class="grid users" action="ajax.php">
    <tr>
                        <th col="id" type="text">ID</th>
        <th col="name" type="text">Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

**Ajax.php**

```
<?php
// connect to db
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("try");

// require our class
require_once("grid.php");
$grid = new Grid("first", array(
"save"=>true,
"delete"=>true
 ));

 ?>
```

Comment: Could you add some detail? What have you tried so far? What have your search results turned up?

Comment: I have Updated the post with added details.Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem recently by calling a secondary php variable, and I had forgotten a single quote. One of my scripts was pointing to a field in my db named - literally -> .field

Check your quotation marks around the word "first" in your primary and ancillary scripts.Look for something like

```
<textarea> ' . $first. (MISSING A ' HERE) </textarea>
```

It should be

```
<textarea>  ' . $first . '  </textarea>
```

Comment: this makes no sense.. can you elaborate on where this is even located in his code?

Comment: I was responding to the title of the question that includes the error message itself, "Unknown column 'first.' in 'field list'". Some script (the code shown references two php scripts for which we have no explicit code) is calling for data from a column named 'first.' that does not exist. The problem seems to be not in the code posted, but in the ancillary scripts not shown.